# call ObservableCollection get accessor again in code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, observablecollection

Is it possible to call the `ObservableCollection` get method again?
i need change `ItemsSource` based on `ComboBox` selection so i need call my `ObservableCollection` again this is my code

```
ObservableCollection<string> sampleData = new ObservableCollection<string>();
public ObservableCollection<string> SampleData
{
    get
    {
        if (sampleData.Count < 1)
            sampleData.Add(line);  

        return sampleData;
    }
}
```

above code run once when application luanch, but i need call it when combobox changed

```
private void CmbFilter_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    switch (cmbFilter.SelectedIndex)
    {
        case 0:         
            break;
        case 1:
            break;
        case 2:
            break;
        case 3:
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: what are you trying to achieve by this? don't you think it is a bad design to create such dependencies?

Comment: yeah i know, i dont know mvvm It's complicated for me

Comment: besides mvvm, your get accessor shouldn't have side effects and moreover a certain logic such as `add` shouldn't be accessed through another property's `get` accessor, it should be a separate method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whole point of an `ObservableCollection` is that you do not need to implement what you are suggesting in your `SampleData` getter. There are 2 approaches you could take here:

**Make use of `ObservableCollection`**

*Note there are better options here but out of scope of the question. Lookup up `SelectedItem` bindings for a `ComboBox`.*

```
private void CmbFilter_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // Modify your collection here based on what was selected.
}
```

**Forget about `ObservableCollection`**

This approach will require you to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` on your ViewModel class.

```
public IEnumerabe<string> SampleData
{
    get
    {
        // Return values based on the selection.
        if (SelectedData == "FirstValueICareAbout") // SelectedData assumes you have investigated how to bind to the SelectedItem of a ComboBox.
        {
            return new[]
            {
                "FirstValue",
                "SecondValue"
            };    
        }

        return Enumerable.Empty<string>();
    }
}

private void CmbFilter_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // Notify the UI that SampleData has changed using INotifyPropertyChanged implementation.
    RaiseNotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(SampleData));
}
```